# Why do easing/tweening function implementations often have multiple parameters?

Tags: animation, math, tween, easing

Most easing function collections I found in my life have complex function signatures, such as jQuery: `function easing (x, t, b, c, d) { ... }`. Examples:

- https://github.com/kikito/tween.lua/blob/master/tween.lua
- http://gizma.com/easing/#l

Why are all these parameters required? Wouldn't it be way easier to just implemente these functions as displayed on http://easings.net/ on a normalized scale, with

- one input value between 0 and 1
- one output value (usually, but not in special cases such as 'elastic') between 0 and 1

and wrap those to work with arbirtrary start/end times and values, using a function such as:

```
function wrapEasing(fn, startTime, endTime, now, startValue, endValue) {
    var progress = (now - startTime) / (endTime - startTime);
    var easedProgress = fn(progress);
    return startValue + easedProgress * (endValue - startValue);
}
```

(This is more of a maths question, I used javascript syntax just as an example -- it applies to all programming languages.)

---

Yes, I found other examples, too:

- https://github.com/CreateJS/TweenJS/blob/master/src/tweenjs/Ease.js

Question is -- why do many people do it the complicated way? Maybe because that would require functional programming?

Comment: Because you need to parametrize your functions. Different speeds, different slopes/gradients, etc. Your wrap-easing function takes a second function which would require the same parameters as the other functions.

Comment: Yes, but writing the easing functions themselves, according to the graphs shown on http://easings.net, would be way easier. You would only work with one possible set of inputs, between 0 and 1. Of course, to *apply* the easing, you need all the values. Just not to calculate the actual "easing progress"